# Why is my class crashing my OCUnit test case with error code 138?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing, ocunit

A class I wrote is crashing my test case with error code 138. The class returns an NSString with the user agent string from UIWebView:

```
@interface MyWebViewUserAgent : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    NSString* userAgent;
    UIWebView* webView;
}

- (NSString*) userAgentString;

@end

#import "MyWebViewUserAgent.h"

@implementation MyWebViewUserAgent

- (NSString*) userAgentString {
    if (userAgent != nil) return userAgent;

    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://127.0.0.1"]]];

    // Wait for the web view to load our bogus request and give us the secret user agent.
        while (userAgent == nil) {
        // This executes another run loop. 
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate: [NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

    NSString *currentDeviceType = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
    NSRange range = [userAgent rangeOfString:currentDeviceType];

    if (range.location == NSNotFound) {

        // Should only happen when iPhone-targeted app is running on an iPad.
        NSRange rangeToReplace = [userAgent rangeOfString:@"iPhone;"];
        if (rangeToReplace.length > 0) {
            userAgent = [userAgent stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rangeToReplace withString:@"iPad;"];
        }
    }
    return userAgent;
}

- (BOOL) webView: (UIWebView*) web_view shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*) request navigationType: (UIWebViewNavigationType) navigation_type {
    userAgent = [request valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"];
    [webView release];
    return NO; // Return no, we don't care about executing an actual request.
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Now, here is my test case:

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyWebViewUserAgent.h"

@interface MyUnitTests : SenTestCase {
    MyWebViewUserAgent *ua;
}

@end

@implementation MySDKUnitTests

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testUserAgentString {
    ua = [[MyWebViewUserAgent alloc] init];
    STAssertNotNil(ua, @"User agent object is nil.");
    STAssertNotNil([ua userAgentString], @"user agent string is nil");
    [ua release];
}

@end
```

The first `STAssertNotNil` in the `testUserAgentString` test works fine but the second `STAssertNotNil` is the line that crashes the test. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `RhythmWebViewUserAgent` a subclass of `MyWebViewUserAgent`?

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to change that class name in that alloc-init. Fixed.

Comment: I just set up a project with your code, and the test passed. So it's not your code, it's something else in your project settings. Do you have other unit tests that work?

Comment: Nope, that's actually the first & only test case I've written thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Your project isn't set up correctly for unit tests. Try [checking these settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546238/unit-tests-fail-then-dont/12624873#12624873). If that fails, try creating a new project, selecting "Include Unit Tests".