# How to set up working logic unit tests target in Xcode 4.5 "Command Line Tool" project?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, linker-errors, xcode4.5, command-line-tool

Having trouble getting unit tests set up for a specific scenario.  Here's what I'm trying:

- In Xcode 4.5, I created a simple OSX **"Command Line Tool"** application project (Foundation).
  Note that Xcode *does not* provide the option to add unit tests to a "Command Line Tool" project automatically – so please don't suggest ticking the ticky-box; it ain't there :-/
- In my project, I created a trivial example class that I'd like to test; e.g. "Shape".
- I followed instructions in Apple's *Xcode Unit Testing Guide* for **[Setting Up Unit-Testing in a Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html)**:

  - I added a unit test target to my project, and
  - I edited the "Test" scheme to run the tests in the new target.
- In the test project's implementation (.m) file, I added an import for `Shape.h` and code in the `setUp()` method to instantiate a shape and assign it to an instance variable.

At that point, I decided to see if things would build and if the default test would run still.  However, when I selected **Product...Test** from the menu, the build failed with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Shape", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ExampleTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Interpreting this error is not the issue. I grok that the unit test target isn't being linked to the binary containing Shape's implementation.  However, I don't (yet) grok Xcode unit testing & target configuration. So:

What do I need to do in order to get the test target linking against the command line tool's resulting output?  Can I link to a command-line executable from the unit test target?  Apple's documentation looks specific to regular OSX applications (`*.app`) and iOS applications, and this is neither.

I have business logic classes that I'd like to develop in a command-line tool setting (to begin with), so I'd like to understand what I need to do to get a unit test target running in a "Command Line Tool" type of project.  *Thank you!*

(p.s. Note that I'm *not* interested in running my unit tests *from* the command line – Stack Overflow already suggested "similar" questions on how to do that – but rather running unit tests *on* a "Command Line Tool" type *project*, and still from within Xcode.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've determined a workaround I find suitable and which doesn't appear to have significant drawbacks, other than an added target.

In a nutshell: the solution involves **adding a static library target** to take advantage of Xcode's ability to create & run unit test code around such a target.  The command line tool target then delegates to the static library, where an alternate `main()`-like function is defined and called by the real `main()` entry point.  The command line tool is kept free of non-trivial code, so the unit test target can access everything worth testing.

Here are the steps:

- From an empty Xcode, from the menu choose *File...New Project*.
- In the resulting dialog, chose *OS X...Application...Command Line Tool*.  For the purpose of this example, I'll assume it is named *SampleCmd*.

After the basic command line tool project has been created:

- From the menu choose *File...New...Target*.
- In the resulting dialog, choose *OS X...Framework & Library...Cocoa Library*.  For the purpose of this example, I'll assume it is named *SampleCmdLogic*.
- **Choose type *Static*, so the command line tool will remain a stand-alone executable.**
- **Make sure the *Include Unit Tests* box is checked.**

After the static library project has been created:

- Copy the `main()` function from `main.m` to `SampleCmdLogic.m`, replacing the `@implementation` block.  (This file will hold the main entry point only. Other files can be added for Objective-C classes, etc.)   **Rename** the function to `libMain()`.
- In `SampleCmdLogic.h`, add a declaration for the new `libMain()`, replacing the `@interface` block:
  `int libMain(int argc, const char * argv[]);`
- In the command line tool's `main.m`, add an `#import "SampleCmdLogic.h"` at top.
- In the command line tool's `main.m`, change the entire contents of the real `main()` function to:
  `return libMain(argc, argv);`

The code is now ready, but there are required linking steps:

- In the project settings for `SampleCmd`, under *Build Phases*, expand *Target Dependencies* and add (+) SampleCmdLogic as a dependency.
- In the project settings for `SampleCmd`, under *Build Phases*, expand *Link Binary With Libraries* and add (+) `libSampleCmdLogic.a`

Everything is now ready.  When you change to the SampleCmd target and choose *Product..Run* from the menu, the build should succeed and output generated as expected.  When you change to the SampleCmdLogic target and choose *Product...Test* from the menu, the build should succeed and the unit tests will run.  The single issue reported will be the initial default failing unit test assertion inserted by Xcode, in `SampleCmdLogicTests.m`.  This is expected.

From this point on, proceed to add all logic and corresponding tests to the SampleCmdLogic target. The SampleCmd target is to remain trivial and providing the command line tool entry point only.

Comment: Funny: I just found myself needing a solution to this very problem! Thanks for coming up with a simple & elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are normally a number of additional steps to add a test target to an app project -- in particular, the setting of Bundle Loader and Test Host as I describe in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12624873/246895.

But when I did them with a Command Line Tool and tried running tests, all it did was run the tool. For an app, it goes through a phase of launching the app, injecting the test bundle into the running app, then executing the tests. But these phases don't apply to Command Line Tools.

So instead of an injected test bundle, what you'll need is a second command-line tool that runs your tests. Then set the your classes so they target the test tool as well as your actual tool. [gh-unit](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) and [google-toolbox-for-mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) both follow this model, so I'd try them.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful at least in that it got me to give up on trying to have the command line tool participate directly in the unit tests.  I instead used a static library target to bring Xcode unit test support back into my project.  Refer to my answer; helps support the famous aphorism *"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection"*  (although this was more a tooling problem, less a science problem.)

Comment: I'll be accepting my own answer on this, but you get the bounty for providing insight that got me thinking about workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the most immediate problem is simply that `Shape` is not included in the new test target.  Try adding `Shape.m` to the test target:

1. Click on Shape.m in Project Navigator
2. Open the Utilities view (View -> Utilities -> Show Utilities)
3. In the Target Membership section of the Utilities view, make sure that both your app *and* test targets are checked.

I don't know if that's the end of your issues with your setup, but it seems like a likely candidate for your most immediate problem.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that in doing this I am simply including my source file to be re-compiled as part of the unit test binary executable, rather than linking to the command-line tool target & using already-compiled code. I'll grant this yields a working unit test project in the simplest case, but not an ideal solution because including and re-compiling source files into the unit test project may introduce subtle differences; e.g. it isn't necessarily the same resulting code being tested. In a real project the compiler options, defined symbols, etc. could potentially differ, n'est-ce pas?